# Hosting multiple sites on IIS having same the IP address

Tags: asp.net, ip, iis-7.5, web-hosting

I need to host multiple sites for testing on single server with one IP Address over IIS.

Currently i have hosted a website which is mapped directly to IP address means no domain name. i need to host another website on same IP. How can i achieve that? is this possible having

e.g 174.22.12.87 (Site1)
e.g 174.22.12.87 :800 (Site2)

I am confused what to put in Host Name and Site Name ? for single IP Address and to host multiple sites. If i put ip in host name in both websites that look fine but what to put in site names? i think they should be unique?

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at this link.
https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b77cf015-017f-489c-9b5b-65ca4a679392.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Make sure to summarize and/or quote relevant sections of links.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same IP-Address, the port is used used to host multiply sites. So you are right.

Comment: I am confused what to put in Host Name and Site Name ? for single IP Address and to host multiple sites. If i put ip in host name in both websites that look fine but what to put in site names? i think they should be unique?

Comment: I didn't worked much with IIS but as far is i know the sitename is only for you to identify your sites in the iis-manager

Answer (score 0):

The combination of IP, Port, and HostName must be unique.

If you're deciding to always leave HostName blank (referencing things by IP:Port instead of domain) then you still just need the combination of IP and Port to be unique.  (i.e. 174.22.12.87:80 vs 174.22.12.87:800)

I believe you're using SiteName to mean the IIS site name, which is just what it shows as within IIS and doesn't impact how you access the site at all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add new `Inbound rule` to open your specified port in `Windows firewall` (server side).